# Can't display one string from array on button press

Tags: android, loops, button

I'm new to arrays in Java and for our final project, instead of creating 3000 activities, I decided to use a single array to house all my strings. The problem I'm now having is that when I press the button to change the string on the screen, it either skips to the end or adds it all together somehow. I want it to show up one string at a time and cannot, for the life of me figure it out.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer Snake;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final String[] Lines = {"So begins the story of our hero.","His name is Solid Snake.","He is an international spy, an elite solider, and quite the ladies man.",
                "Snake likes to sneak around in his cardboard box.","Most enemies aren't smart enough to catch him in it."};
        Snake = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.maintheme);
        Snake.start();
        final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Button N = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
        Button B = (Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
        int count = 0;
        tv.setText(Lines[count]);

        N.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String temp = "";
                for(int l=1; l<Lines.length; l++){
                    temp=temp+Lines[l];
                    tv.setText(""+temp);
                }

            }

            });
        };
```

The main problem is in the button press. I've searched everywhere and couldn't find any answer to this at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are, indeed, a life-saver. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please don't forget to choose the right answer if your question was solved ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the button is clicked the text is changed through each entry in the array, finishing on the last one. Since this happens quickly you only see the last value.

Your `onClick()` method should be changed to only call `setText()` once and increment a counter that is held in the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int currentLine = 0;
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        tv.setText(Lines[currentLine]);

        N.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentLine + 1 < Lines.length) {
                    currentLine++;
                    tv.setText(Lines[currentLine]);
                }
            }
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```